# Laravel Scout pagination overextends on Algolia record limit

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, algolia, laravel-scout

I've looked at many Stackoverflow questions regarding this issue. All the solutions are outdated and it puzzles me why this isn't being brought up more.

**The Issue**

I have a query that fetches all the products from the Algolia index called `products`. In that index, there are over 20k records.

Whenever I query the records and display them on the front end using the `->pagination()` helper and the `$product->links()`. It shows that over **400** pages are visible. Whenever I click over the 27th page or so, it stops fetching. Whats the issue here? I understand that there is a 1000 records limit in place, but its only fetching 36 records per page, shouldn't it just re-fetch on each page? Im not fetching all 20k records at one.

[image]

Comment: https://discourse.algolia.com/t/pagination-limit/10585 does this help

Comment: u need to set it at indexing time not search time

Comment: idk if related https://www.algolia.com/doc/framework-integration/laravel/indexing/configure-index/?client=php

Comment: yea not really helpful since it doesn't answer my question. I am paginating 36 records per page. its not fetching anything more than 36 records.

So the 1000 limit doesn't really apply here. It shows I have 436 pages, when I click on any page after page 27, no records are returned

Comment: hi do you have access to network tab algolia request. is the nbPages 36 or 436

Comment: i dont know about laravel scout but have worked with instantsearch. the result coming from algolia has hitsPerPage, nbHits, nbPages, page. in your case looks like `nbPages:27`, `hitsPerPage:36`. `nbHits:17500ish`. how did you create pagination component. is it coming from  a library or did you manually calculate the no of pages as  `nbHits/hitsPerPage`.

Comment: this is what i use:
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/scout#pagination

Comment: i see, looks like theres a abstraction layer on top. i don't really know why the no of pages is 400+ . it should be 27. do you have a way to log a result coming from algolia by any chance

Comment: anyway the reason why it wont fetch is beyond page 27 is because paginationLimitedTo is 1000 by default